# Is it possible to make my pi an access point while connected to wifi?

Tags: wifi, ssh

My goal is to be able to connect my pi to my wifi network, while still having it possible to connect to the pi itself through my phone or laptop so I can SSH into it. Is that possible?

Comment: You will most likely need separate radios to have this functionality, ie, in build wifi connecting to your wifi network and a usb wifi adapter to have a hotspot or vice-versa. Other solution would be to be on the same network and use RPi's ip address to ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can buy a second WiFi adapter like Edimax EW-7811Un and follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/martinsauter/WLAN-VPN-Pi). However, after couple years of procrastination with installing the project, I just went ahead and got GL.iNet GL-AR300M which essentially is a tiny ARM-based computer already configured with everything you might possibly need and is comparable in cost to Pi 3. GL.iNet GL-AR150 is even cheaper and does the same thing.